# Make a MatLab table out of 2 Cell Array

Tags: matlab, matrix

What is the most efficient way to generate a table from 2 cell arrays. Array A contains data and Array B contains the corresponding names. I would like to combine them into a convenient table structure.

```
Cell_Array_A =
{[10x10],[10x10],[];
 [10x11],[],[10x12];
 [9x10],[13x10],[]}

Cell_Array_B = 
{['A','B',[];
 'B',[],'A';
 'B','A',[]}
```

It should generate a table with the headers 'A' and 'B'. However, in my real data set, I have a lot of variable names, which I don't know. So I need a way to read all variables from the first row and use them to create the table for the rest of the matrix.

Example of the desired output:

```
'A' 'B'
[10x10] [10x10]
[10x12] [10x11]
[13x10] [9x10]
```

I tried so far to process the arrays row wise to get rid of the empty arrays. However this is not very efficient. I run the following code for each row in Array A and B. Below an example for the first row in Array A which I later on use as the tablet for my table.

```
order_row = {};
order_row = Cell_Array_A(1,:);
ordered_filenames = order_row(~cellfun('isempty',order_row));
```

Comment: What's the desired output, in this example?

Comment: Also post the inefficient code

Comment: I added the corresponding desired table structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited answer** The idea is 1) to collect the non-empty column headers, 2) for each unique column header collect the corresponding values:

```
    % Unique variable names
    nul_names = cellfun(@isempty,Cell_Array_B);
    var_names = unique(Cell_Array_B(~nul_names));

    % Function to find a column header index
    ixhead = @(h,c) cellfun(@(x) isequaln(x,h), c(:));

    % Collect the values
    var_values = cellfun( ...
       @(h) Cell_Array_A(ixhead(h, Cell_Array_B)), var_names, ...
       'UniformOutput', false ...
    );

    % Create the table
    tbl = table(var_values{:}, 'VariableNames', var_names);
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! Array A contains data and Array B contains the corresponding names. How would you solve this, if you don't know the names and you want to retrieve them from the first line in Array B?

Comment: That is a different problem. Please update your question accordingly, and I will update the answer.

Comment: I updated the question. Your previous answer was excellent and adding the possibility of further unknown variables will make this broadly applicable.

Comment: @C.Colden Sorry, I'm a bit busy right now, I'll be back in 1 hour with the answer.

Comment: @C.Colden The answer is updated. I hope it suits your needs. Is not the most efficient (mostly due to presence of `[]` in the second cell array)